# The new RestClient in Spring boot 3.2, how to log the outgoing requests and responses?

Tags: spring-boot

I couldn't find how to configure the log levels in application.yml to enable logging the requests and response that been send by the new RestClient in Spring boot 3.2.

I know that I can use an interceptor to accomplish this, but I prefer to use the default logging mechanism in Spring.

Comment: afaik there is no as it depends on the used client, there isn't one for a `RestTemplate` either.

Comment: @M.Deinum Yes, by default it seem RestClient use `HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory` which it using Apache HttpClient . 
I added 
`logging.level.org.apache.http=debug` but nothing comes up. I believe I miss something.

Comment: What is used is based on what is included. How to enable logging should be in the library used, also it might very well be that the library doesn't support request/response logging. All in all the restclient uses the same components as the RestTemplate does. So how to enable it there, is the way to enable it in the restclient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With Spring Framework's new [RestClient](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/reference/integration/rest-clients.html) you can use several `RequestFactories`. As you pointed out in your comment, you're using `HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory` for [Apache HttpComponents](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-5.3.x/index.html).

#### A Sample Service

```java
@Service
public class RestSampleService {
    private static final String BASE_URL = "https://api.github.com/users/";
    public GitHubUser getGithubUser(final String username) {
        final var restClient = RestClient.builder()
            .requestFactory(new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory())
            .baseUrl(BASE_URL + username)
            .build();

        return restClient.get().retrieve().body(GitHubUser.class);
    }
}
```

The `getGithubUser()` method retrieves a GitHub user's information from its public API.

Here is a sample POJO for (de)serialization:

```java
public class GitHubUser {

    public GitHubUser() {
        // For Jackson
    }

    String login;
    String id;
    String url;
    String name;
    // Add'l fields, getters and setters are omitted for brevity
}
```

A CommandLineRunner to verify logging:

```java
static final Logger logger =  LoggerFactory.getLogger(SpringSandboxApplication.class);

@Bean
public CommandLineRunner commandLineRunner(RestSampleService restSampleService) {
    return (args) -> {
        final var username = "tcsizmadia";
        final var githubUser = restSampleService.getGithubUser(username);
        logger.info("GitHub user '" + username + "' Full name: '" + githubUser.getName() + "'");
    };
}
```

For detailed informations how to configure logging see the Apache HttpClient's official documentation's [Logging section](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-5.3.x/logging.html).

Here, in my `application.properties` file, I've configured my Spring PoC Application to log requests and responses:

```
logging.level.org.apache.hc.client5.http=DEBUG
```

Sample log entries:

```
2024-01-09T16:24:09.400+01:00 DEBUG 62611 --- [           main] org.apache.hc.client5.http.headers       : http-outgoing-0 >> GET /users/tcsizmadia HTTP/1.1
2024-01-09T16:24:09.400+01:00 DEBUG 62611 --- [           main] org.apache.hc.client5.http.headers       : http-outgoing-0 >> Accept-Encoding: gzip, x-gzip, deflate
2024-01-09T16:24:09.400+01:00 DEBUG 62611 --- [           main] org.apache.hc.client5.http.headers       : http-outgoing-0 >> Host: api.github.com
2024-01-09T16:24:09.400+01:00 DEBUG 62611 --- [           main] org.apache.hc.client5.http.headers       : http-outgoing-0 >> Connection: keep-alive
2024-01-09T16:24:09.400+01:00 DEBUG 62611 --- [           main] org.apache.hc.client5.http.headers       : http-outgoing-0 >> User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/5.2.3 (Java/18.0.1)
2024-01-09T16:24:09.400+01:00 DEBUG 62611 --- [           main] org.apache.hc.client5.http.wire          : http-outgoing-0 >> "GET /users/tcsizmadia HTTP/1.1[\r][\n]"
2024-01-09T16:24:09.400+01:00 DEBUG 62611 --- [           main] org.apache.hc.client5.http.wire          : http-outgoing-0 >> "Accept-Encoding: gzip, x-gzip, deflate[\r][\n]"
2024-01-09T16:24:09.400+01:00 DEBUG 62611 --- [           main] org.apache.hc.client5.http.wire          : http-outgoing-0 >> "Host: api.github.com[\r][\n]"
2024-01-09T16:24:09.400+01:00 DEBUG 62611 --- [           main] org.apache.hc.client5.http.wire          : http-outgoing-0 >> "Connection: keep-alive[\r][\n]"
2024-01-09T16:24:09.400+01:00 DEBUG 62611 --- [           main] org.apache.hc.client5.http.wire          : http-outgoing-0 >> "User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/5.2.3 (Java/18.0.1)[\r][\n]"
...
```

Comment: `logging.level.org.apache.hc.client5.http=DEBUG` what I was missing . Answer accepted

Comment: Ahh gotcha! Then sorry for the too verbose answer. I wanted to make sure that everything was explained.

Answer (score 0):

When you add '.requestFactory(new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory())'
its not possible to write a tests with @RestClientTest for that RestClient.
Topic:https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/38832

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).